# Como guardar la visibilidad de un boton

Tags: android, botón

quería saber cual seria la mejor forma de guardar la visibilidad de un botón en shared preferences. Tengo varios botones y necesito que algunos estén visibles  otros no según lo que se elija y al volver a entrar permanezcan de esa forma

Esta es la manera en que lo estaba haciendo pero no se guarda

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button b1, b2;
    TextView tv1;
    private static final String boton1_Visible = "boton1_Visible";
    private static final String boton2_Visible = "boton2_Visible";
    private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);

        mSharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        boton1_Visible.setVisibility((mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(boton1_Visible, true)
                ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE));

        boton2_Visible.setVisibility((mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(boton2_Visible, true)
                ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void a(View view){

        boton1_Visible.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        boolean visibility1 = boton1_Visible.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE;
        boton1_Visible.setVisibility(visibility1 ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE);

        mSharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(boton1_Visible, visibility1).apply();

        boton2_Visible.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        boolean visibility2 = boton2_Visible.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
        boton2_Visible.setVisibility(visibility2 ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);

        mSharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(boton2_Visible, visibility2).apply();
    }
}
```

Comment: Debes revisar mejor la lógica del método a(View view)

Comment: Agrega tu layout activity_main.xml

Comment: @Keops el método a(View view) seguramente esta definido dentro del layout, lo comento porque veo recibe una vista como parámetro.

Comment: Hola @Elenasys estoy seguro que es como lo describes, solo quería ver la visibilidad de sus botones, saludos  =).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes diferenciar que botón es el que esta recibiendo el evento para cambiar su visibilidad y/o cambiar el estado del preferences.

Espero que te sirva amigo, saludos

```
public class MainTestActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button b1, b2;
    TextView tv1;
    private static final String boton1_Visible = "boton1_Visible";
    private static final String boton2_Visible = "boton2_Visible";
    private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_2);

        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);

        mSharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        boolean vB1 = mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(boton1_Visible, true);


        b1.setVisibility((vB1     ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE));
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);

        boolean vB2 = (mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(boton2_Visible, true));
        b2.setVisibility(vB2 ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.b1:
                boolean visibility1 = b1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
                b1.setVisibility(visibility1 ? View.INVISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
                mSharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(boton1_Visible, !visibility1).apply();

                break;
            case R.id.b2:

                boolean visibility2 = b2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
                b2.setVisibility(visibility2 ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE);
                mSharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(boton2_Visible, !visibility2).apply();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Te sugiero dos métodos, para guardar y obtener el valor.

```
private String PREFS_KEY = "mispreferencias";

public void guardaValorPreferencia(Context context, String key, boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}



public boolean obtieneValorPreferencia(Context context, String key) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    return  preferences.getBoolean(key, "");
}
```

Para guardar y obtener los valores que corresponden a la visibilidad de los botones realizarías los siguiente, usando los métodos anteriores:

Supongo que el método `a()` es un método definido en el layout al dar click a los botones, entonces:

```
public void a(View view){

    boton1_Visible.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    boolean visibility1 = boton1_Visible.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE;
    boton1_Visible.setVisibility(visibility1 ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE);

   //mSharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(boton1_Visible, visibility1).apply();
   //Guarda valores correspondientes a visibilidad.
    guardaValorPreferencia(getApplicationContext(), boton1_Visible, visibility1);

    boton2_Visible.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    boolean visibility2 = boton2_Visible.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
    boton2_Visible.setVisibility(visibility2 ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);

    //mSharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(boton2_Visible, visibility2).apply();
   //Guarda valores correspondientes a visibilidad.
    guardaValorPreferencia(getApplicationContext(), boton2_Visible, visibility2);

}
```

y al iniciar tu Activity puedes obtener los valores para asignar visibilidad a los botones:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);

        mSharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//Obtiene valores de visibilidad.   
boton1_Visible.setVisibility(obtieneValorPreferencia(getApplicationContext(), boton1_Visible) ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE));

boton2_Visible.setVisibility(obtieneValorPreferencia(getApplicationContext(), boton2_Visible) ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE));

    }
```